# Element-in-List testing

Tags: xslt

For a stylesheet I'm writing (actually for a set of them, each generating a different output format), I have the need to evaluate whether a certain value is present in a list of values. In this case, the value being tested is taken from an element's attribute. The list it is to be tested against comes from the invocation of the stylesheet, and is taken as a top-level `<xsl:param>` (to be provided on the command-line when I call `xsltproc` or a Saxon equivalent invocation). For example, the input value may be:

```
v0_01,v0_10,v0_99
```

while the attribute values will each look very much like *one* such value. (Whether a comma is used to separate values, or a space, is not important-- I chose a comma for now because I plan on passing the value via command-line switch to `xsltproc`, and using a space would require quoting the argument, and I'm lazy-enough to not want to type the extra two characters.)

What I am looking for is something akin to Perl's `grep`, wherein I can see if the value I currently have is contained in the list. It can be done with sub-string tests, but this would have to be clever so as not to get a false-positive (`v0_01` should not match a string that contains `v0_011`). It seems that the only non-scalar data-type that XSL/XSLT supports is a node-set. I suppose it's possible to convert the list into a set of text nodes, but that seems like over-kill, even compared to making a sub-string test with extra boundaries-checking to prevent false matches.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, using XPath string functions is the right way to do it. All you have to make sure is that you test for the delimiters as well:

```
contains(concat(',' $list, ','), concat(',', $value, ','))
```

would return a Boolean value. Or you might use one of these:

```
substring-before(concat('|,' $list, ',|'), concat(',', $value, ','))
```

or

```
substring-after(concat('|,' $list, ',|'), concat(',', $value, ','))
```

If you get an empty string as the result, `$value` is not in the list.

EDIT:

@Dimitre's comment is correct: `substring-before()` (or `substring-after()`) would also return the empty string if the found string is the first (or the last) in the list. To avoid that, I added *something* at the start and the end of the list. Still `contains()` is the recommended way of doing this.

Comment: Actually, for my purposes, it looks like the "contains" function will do (using the padding you suggest). What tripped me up, was that I was looking for this functionality within XSLT itself, when I should have been looking in XPath.

Comment: Added the contains() function, that one had escaped me. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak: The substring-before() expression will evaluate to '' even if the value is contained in the list (when it is the first value). Similarly, the substring-after() expression evaluates to '' when the value is the last in the list. Therefore, only the contains() expression is correct

Comment: @Tomalak: Therefore, these two expressions must be or-ed together, but this is much longer and probably significantly less efficient than the contains() expression.

Comment: Okay, so I would change the concat() a bit to account for that.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the XPath 1.0 solution provided by Tomalak,


**Using XPath 2.0** one can tokenize the list of values:

**`exists(tokenize($list, ',')[. = $value])`**

evaluates to `true()` if and only if `$value` is contained in the list of values `$list`

Comment: Is not it better to write this way:
tokenize($list, ',') = $value

Comment: @lagivan, It depends what we understand by better. I think then using "exists" (as a word or concept) is immediately more understandable and natural to people, who are not accustomed to the shortcuts of XPath. Also, the "exists()" function might be better optimized than a general value comparison.